# CSS column rule styling?

Tags: html, css

ok, so basically i am trying to apply a gradient to a column rule but the results are not... as expected.

maybe i am missing something?

```
.rule { 
     border: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     width: 1px;
     height: 200px;
     background: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
     float: left;
     }

 .columns {
     float: left;
     margin: 3.5em 1em;
     width: 80%;
     -ms-column-count: 2;
     -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
     column-count: 2;
     column-gap: 4em;

 /* this works */
     -ms-column-rule: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
     -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
     -moz-column-rule: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1); 
     column-rule: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);

 /* this does not */
  /* -moz-column-rule: 1px solid radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
     -ms-column-rule: 1px solid radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
     -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
     column-rule: 1px solid radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
 */ 
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VileTouch/0exLthpq/

ok, so this is how it ended up. without column rule and using :before and :after selectors. fully scalable. thanks for all the answers.
https://jsfiddle.net/VileTouch/0exLthpq/3/

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: i mean, sure, i could get rid of the the column properties (and their vendor prefixes!) and use hr instead, but then the hr won't accept a 100% height value, (which means it won't scale with the paragraphs.), so...yes, i'm pretty sure i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `<hr />`, which doesn't act as expected in a lot of cases, simply use a `<div>` with a width of 1px or 2px and apply the background to that div. In this case, you will need to float it left to place it "into the grid" with your other elements and account for the space it takes up.

`<hr />`'s actually have their border colored (by default), not via color: or background:. Plus, there are a ton of browser-specific things you must override, like shadows.

Divs will act more like you expect when you want more custom styling.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could use an :after element on the column itself, but that's a whole new CSS lesson.

Comment: so it is not possible to style the [column property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-rule.asp) beyond the (limited) scope of the spec?

Comment: Honestly, I avoid the column property because of it's wonky browser support so I don't entirely know. With things like columns and hrs, you either style it like it wants to be styled or you style something else that acts like you expect it to, or you bang your head against the wall. In this case, it seems like you want 3 columns with fading separators. I would do that via a grid and divs acting as separators with all the CSS you want on them.

Comment: looks like that's what i'm going to have to do... too bad, because columns seem like a very good idea (text overflowing to a different column dynamically) ...if only it was more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

try it with different divs instead of column-rule.

css:

```
.g {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.33, rgb(14,173,173)), color-stop(0.67, rgb(0,255,255)));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(14,173,173) 33%, rgb(0,255,255) 67% );
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
position:absolute;
}

.g > div { background: #fff; }

#rechts{
  float: right;
  width:49%;
  height:100%;
    }
    #links{
      width:49%;
      position:absolute;
      height:100%;
    }
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="g">
    <div id="links">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
<div id="rechts">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

--> [plunker with div](https://plnkr.co/edit/tyWIHuWqLR2V2XIZ5ayC?p=preview)